# How do I specify scaling triggers in .elasticbeanstalk configuration

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My configuration generated by eb init contains the following:

```
[aws:autoscaling:asg]
Custom Availability Zones=
MaxSize=2
MinSize=1
```

How can I specify to use a different scaling trigger in the optionsettings file?

Can I perhaps use some approach through .ebextensions?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using ebextensions for this usecase as that will give you more flexibility  in the manner you deploy your code. Read about possible option setting values here.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html

Create a .ebextensions directory in your app source. Create a file with .config extension in this directory.  Use the aws:autoscaling:trigger namespace. The file should have YAML syntax.
Example Contents:

```
option_settings:
      - namespace: aws:autoscaling:trigger
        option_name: BreachDuration
        value: 300
```

The files in the ebextensions directory are processed in alphabetical order.

More information on ebextensions here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html